# UITableView artifact when created in code

Tags: c#, ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios

I create a UITableView in code using the following:

```
// no xib
tableView = new UITableView(
new RectangleF(0,0, this.View.Frame.Width, this.View.Frame.Height),
UITableViewStyle.Grouped);
tableView.Delegate = new VideoLibraryTVDelegate();
tableView.DataSource = new VideoLibraryTableViewDataSource(this);
tableView.AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth |   
                             UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight;
tableView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromPatternImage(this.backgroundImage);
tableView.SeparatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.SingleLine;

tableView.SizeToFit ();
tableView.Frame = new RectangleF (0, 0, this.View.Frame.Width, this.View.Frame.Height);
        this.View.AddSubview(tableView);
```

The resulting UITableView has a visual artifact:

[image]

The row height is done with

```
public override float GetHeightForRow (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    return tableView.RowHeight * 2.0f;
}
```

How do I get rid of the extra lines over the table cells?

**Edit**: Turns out the problem was that I defined the container controller to inherit from UITableViewController rather than UIViewController. With the code in the original question this problem would not have been evident.

Comment: If you're doing a lot (or even few) of tables I suggest you to look at MonoTouch.Dialog (https://github.com/migueldeicaza/MonoTouch.Dialog) as it will simplify your life (or at least your code) a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was that I defined the container controller to inherit from `UITableViewController` rather than `UIViewController`. With the code in the original question this problem would not have been evident.

Answer (score 2):

Just multiply the tableView's RowHeight by 2, and don't override GetHeightForRow().  For your case, it is a constant value, so you don't need it.

```
tableView.RowHeight *= 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I see that's off is the call to [tableView sizeToFit]. You usually don't call it on tableview, and I can only imagine that's affecting the rendering of the given UITableViewCell. Also MonoTouch.Dialog is da-bomb-dot-com there's even a obj-C port of it called QuickDialog:

https://github.com/escoz/QuickDialog

Thanks,

Anuj